# Django- Staticfiles 404 on runserver

Tags: django, django-settings, django-staticfiles

I'm not doing anything fancy. Just trying to get my static files to work using `python manage.py runserver` with `Debug = True`

`'django.contrib.staticfiles'` is installed.

These are my **static settings**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Here is my **template syntax**:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<title>Dashboard</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="{% static "boostrap/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}"
      rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="{% static "boostrap/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" %}"
              rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Timeline CSS -->
<link href="{% static "boostrap/dist/css/timeline.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="{% static "boostrap/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
<link href="{% static "boostrap/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="
{% static "boostrap/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

`findstatic` can successfully locate these files when entered exactly as they are in the template:

```
(AlmondKing) C:\Projects\AlmondKing>python manage.py findstatic bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css --verbosity 2
Found 'bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' here:
  C:\Projects\AlmondKing\AlmondKing\static\bootstrap\bower_components\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css
Looking in the following locations:
  C:\Projects\AlmondKing\AlmondKing\static
  C:\Users\Adam\Envs\AlmondKing\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static
```

My URLS have no conflict:

**ROOT URLS:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('AlmondKing.AKGenius.urls', namespace="AKGenius")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^purchases/', include('AlmondKing.InventoryLogs.urls', namespace="purchases")),
    url(r'^company/', include('AlmondKing.FinancialLogs.urls',namespace="company")),
]
```

**AKGenius URLS:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name="home"),
    url(r'^dashboard/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='control_panel.html'), name="dashboard"),
    url(r'^support/$', 'AlmondKing.AKGenius.views.support'),
]
```

and the paths seem to be rendering correctly to the browser:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="/static/boostrap/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
```

And yes, I've restarted runserver since my last settings change.

What could be causing these to 404? Would it have something to do with Windows?

Comment: Are you sure those URLs for your CSS are correct? Should "boostrap" be "bootstrap"?

Comment: Wow. I think I would have given up programming for good before I would have caught that. And I replicated the same error on all of them. Thanks so much for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And as a proper answer in case anybody else comes across this post at a later date:

Looks like there's a typo in each line, where

{% static "boostrap

should be

{% static "boo**t**strap